# How can I minimize code here so that its more memory efficient in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.6, primes

I was going through problems on www.spoj.com and the prime generator problem caught my attention as a good warmup problem to get started.
The problem is straight forward and easy to code. But, every time I submit my code I get a run time error. I'm guessing it's a code efficiency problem and I would love to expand my knowledge on what is memory efficient and what is not.
https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

```
import numpy as np
run_times = int(input())
for i in range(run_times):
    search_range = list(map(int, input().split()))
    for j in range(search_range[0], search_range[1]):
        a = j%np.arange(2, j)
        if 0 in a:
            pass
        elif 0 not in a and j>0 :
            print(j)
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  Also, using `_` as a identifier when you actually are using the value leads to very difficult to read code.

Comment: the error is (runtime error, time limit exceeded), I was planing on replacing the _ with a more readable identifier. Guess i just missed that sry

Comment: The error you're getting is related to the speed of the program - not the memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far from optimal, but is a simple rework that should improve your code speed siginificantly and fix a couple of bugs:

```
import numpy as np

run_times = int(input())

for _ in range(run_times):
    start, stop = map(int, input().split())

    for number in range(max(start, 2), stop + 1):

        array = number % np.arange(2, int(number ** 0.5) + 1)

        if 0 not in array:
            print(number)
```

Bugs-wise, your code outputs 1 as a prime but it shouldn't.  Also, given the range '3 5' your code outputs '3' but the example shows '3 5' so you don't have your end point set correctly.  Finally, your `j > 0` comes late in your code (after you've done work you'll end up throwing away) and isn't necessary as the problem indicates a minimum of 1 as input.

Speed-wise, let's consider a worst case based on the problem description:

```
1
999900000 1000000000
```

My revised code should solve this in just under a minute.  I don't believe yours will have even found it's first prime in that amount of time.  If this isn't fast enough, there's more that could be done.  (E.g treat 2 as a special case and only compute with odd numbers; reuse calculations instead of tossing them, etc.)

None of this is about memory efficiency -- it's all about using a correct algorithm.